# How to close a window without closing the whole program?

Tags: delphi, authentication, tform

in my application i have two forms let's say, LoginForm and AccountForm

The LoginForm is set as the main Form, it is the form when the user is able to login from to his account ( two TEdits and login Button ). When a user type his login details and connect, a new form which is AccountForm is opened.

How to close the LoginForm on login success without closing the whole application? or in such language how to use the code below to close the Login form only but not the application.

```
if (not IncludeForm.sqlquery1.IsEmpty) and (isblacklisted='0') and (isactivated='1')  then
begin // Login Successful *** Show the account window
AccountForm.Show;
LoginFrom.Close; // <----The problem is in this line, using this line causes the whole application to close***}
end;
```

Thankyou

Comment: Bounty:"Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources." I am credible. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fetch [here](http://delphi.about.com/library/weekly/code/password_login_mainform.zip) the source code of the excellent article [Display a LogIn / Password Dialog Before the Main Form is Created](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/password_login.htm) by [Zarko Gajic](http://delphi.about.com/bio/Zarko-Gajic-3522.htm)
.

Excerpt:

```
program PasswordApp;

uses
  Forms,
  main in 'main.pas' {MainForm},
  login in 'login.pas' {LoginForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  if TLoginForm.Execute then
  begin
    Application.Initialize;
    Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm) ;
    Application.Run;
  end
  else
  begin
    Application.MessageBox('You are not authorized to use the application. The password is "delphi".', 'Password Protected Delphi application') ;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: +1 Makes sense to add an Execute method to TLogin form. Since it is a quite specific form, a class method will do, but I'd rather make it an instance method to be more in line with other dialogs. Nevertheless a good solution. Articles from delphi.about.com do usually make sense. :)

Answer (score 10):

Don't make LoginForm the main form. If you create the loginform using
`LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create` instead of `Application.CreateForm`, the form won't be set as the application main form. The first form created using Application.CreateForm will be the main form.
You can edit your project file (.dpr) to alter it like this:

```
program YourApp;

uses
  Forms,
  fLoginForm in 'fLoginForm.pas' {LoginForm},
  fMainForm in 'fMainForm.pas' {MainForm};

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  with TLoginForm.Create(nil) do
  try
    ShowModal;
  finally
    Free;
  end;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

You could also create your own application main loop that checks for specific forms being opened, but that's a bit harder and a bit more fragile than the solution above.

Comment: +1 This is a nice example of where `with TMyObject.Create(..) do` works well. You actively don't want a variable so that you can be sure it is never referenced beyond this little block. It would be wise to point out that the automatically created `LoginForm: TLoginForm` variable in `fLoginForm` should be deleted.

Comment: I would add some kind of logic to the TLoginForm ie: `if (ShowModal = mrOK) then ...` only if the login was successful you need to create the `MainForm`.

Comment: @kobik. Maybe, although the application may still want to show the main form with a slightly different UI. Or the login form could, for instance, have called Application.Terminate, thus causing the main form never to be shown. But I have to admit, I haven't even attempted to address this issue in my answer.